# Why are certain class names not colored by Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, c++11, ide, visual-studio-2012, visual-assist

`'thread'` and `'function'` are STL class names like `'vector', 'list', etc.`

Yet `'thread'` and `'function'` are not colored in the text editor of Visual Studio 2012, while `'vector'` and `'list'` are normal.

Why and how to fix?

PS:

`'std::thread'` is fine; but `'thread'` (without the prefix `std::`) is still not colored.

Also, Visual AssistX is enabled. I've tried to disable Visual AssistX, but no effect.

Comment: No. thread is indeed not a template class. The original post has been revised. Thanks.

Comment: Works fine on my machine™.  Changing the theme is popular.  Consider resetting it back to get a fresh starting point.

Comment: Have you considered that Visual Assist may be the problem?

Comment: I've tried to disable Visual AssistX, but no effect.

Answer (score 0):

std::thread is colored in my environment. This is decided by your environment settings, you can import such or make your own under Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors in VS 2012. There are several themes for free online.

Comment: std::thread is fine on my machine; but thread (without prefix std::) is not

Comment: I also use Visual AssistX. It may be the culprit.